# Ajax inserting duplicate records in Mysql Database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have the following Ajax Code for submitting data to Mysql DB.

```
<script>
var amountdue;
var amount;
$('#btn-submit').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($("#customer").validationEngine('validate')) {
    swal({
      title: "Submit Confirmation",
      text: "Are you sure to submit the data?",
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#126495",
      confirmButtonText: "Submit",
      closeOnConfirm: false
    }, 
    function(isConfirm){
      if (isConfirm) {
        amountdue =  "<?php echo $amount_due;?>";
        amount = "<?php echo $amount;?>";
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "submit.php",
          cache: false,
          dataType : "text",
          data: {amountdue : amountdue, amount : amount},
          success: function(data) {
            window.location.href = 'customers';
          },
          error: function(result) {
            swal({
              title: "Error",
              type: "warning",
              text: "Sorry, the data could not be updated due to some reasons.",
              confirmButtonColor: "#126495"
            });
          }
        });
      } //confirm
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

The issue is that **sometimes (Not always)** data is getting inserted 2 and more times in mysql DB..How can i prevent this behavior on Ajax Submit ??

will `$('#btn-submit').unbind();`

work on success ?? Requesting help...

Comment: can you indent your code please, it is quote hard to read in this manner

Comment: indented code...

Comment: here is nothing that indicates a double firing, could it be done in the submit.php

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing where or why this would double-submit unless something the `swal` is doing itself which is causing it to hit its own callback more than once.

Comment: Not sure whether sweetalert is the culprit.. Will unbiding and binding again help ??
success: function(data) {
$('#btn-submit').unbind();
$('#btn-submit').bind('click');
window.location.href = 'customers';
},

Comment: Look into the network tab (browser devtools) to inspect the ajax calls to confirm that ajax is in fact firing off twice. If it is, start peppering all your js with `console.log('debug text');` so you can then monitor exactly what is going on in the console, you can add variables, and whatever to the console log events to help you pinpoint it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

As the first line of your click event handler, do

```
e.disabled = true;
```

Then, in both your success and error handlers for AJAX, do this

```
e.disabled = false;
```

The point of this is to suppress unintentional double clicks on your button until the AJAX operation finishes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btn-submit').off().on('click',function(e){
 ……..Your code...
```

Try like this.